# embed pdf file in the same way as svg file (without grey background)

Tags: html, pdf, svg

It's possible to embed pdf files, but I would like to customize it a little bit more.

For example, look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5CALy/2/), with the following code:

```
<object data='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58922976/test.pdf#view=FitH&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&statusbar=0&messages=0&navpanes=0' 
        type='application/pdf' 
        width='72%' 
        height='100px'>

<p>It appears your Web browser is not configured to display PDF files. 
No worries, just <a href='https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58922976/test.pdf'>click here to download the PDF file.</a></p>
</object>
<object data="http://tinyurl.com/punrrgs" width="72%"> </object>
```

I would like to be able to get the exact same result for the pdf as I have with the svg. They both look very similar now (in chrome), the only difference is this grey/brown background of the pdf reader. Is it possible to hide this background ? Or maybe set this background to white so you can't notice it ?

Edit: I was thinking that using a white border and negative padding this could have worked, sadly negative paddings are not allowed. Any other creative way to get a white border in the place the grey adobe reader border is now located.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch plugin into FullScreenMode(Ctrl + L) and change **Full Screen Appearance** (it will work on a client side only, you can't do it via parameters [link](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf))

> Background Color Specifies the window’s background color in Full
>   Screen mode. You can select a color from the color palette to
>   customize the background color.